# Understanding the behavior of Android's BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

I have an Android App with a MainActivity and an instance of a BroadcastReceiver to receive a GCM push notification. Everything is working fine and I receive the notifications without a problem.

However, I have noticed that whenever I receive a push notification, MainActivity is also initiated and started. This causes both entry points of my app to be called (the BroadcastReceiver and MainActivity), causing a few problems.

I want to understand whether this is the normal behavior of a BroadcastReceiver to launch the main activity of the app. If this is the normal behavior, is it possible to change it and not start MainActivity when the BroadcastReceiver is called?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to understand whether this is the normal behavior of a BroadcastReceiver to launch the main activity of the app.

No. In all likelihood, you are calling `startActivity()` on your `MainActivity` somewhere yourself, in your code, that is causing this.